# PHP # Accessing protected or private Variables of class by reference intended or a bug?

Tags: php

### Explanation

While researching, I created this little code snippet below to get to know php better.
The reason why I now create this question is to reach more experienced developers in order to not clog the system too much and don't bring this further than it has to.

Below is a code example on how to access a private or protected Variable outside the scope the class.

---

### Code Example

This code example will setup `$TestVar` to be a reference to the private Variable `test::A` inside of the `test` class.

```
<?php
class Test {
    private $A = 123;
    
    public function changeA ($Var){
        $this->A = $Var;
    }
    
    public function createReference(){
        return([&$this->A]);
    }
}

$TestClass = new Test();
$TestVar = &$TestClass->createReference()[0];
```

---

By either using `Test::changeA()` or changing `$TestVar` the content of `test::A` can be changed.

```
//Test Current Value
var_dump($TestVar);

//Change test::A the intended way
$TestClass->changeA(321);
var_dump($TestVar);

//Change it by reference
$TestVar = 777;
var_dump($TestVar);
var_dump($TestClass);
```

---

Expected Output:

```
int 123
int 321
int 777

object(Test)[1]
  private 'A' => int 777
```

---

### Result

The reason why I see this as a bug, [The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) states in both description and examples:

> Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inheriting and parent classes.

> Members declared as private may only be accessed by the class that defines the member.

for this to not be possible or intended.

Is this a bug, a wrong documentation or simply an error someone has to live with.

Comment: I used PHP 7.* in this example and am uncertain if this is possible in PHP 5

Comment: The symbol `$A`, which is scoped to members of the `Test` class, is indeed private, meaning accessible only to members of the `Test` class. However, that doesn't stop you from creating a *reference* to that symbol, and making that reference available outside the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behaviour is perfectly normal. In fact, if your properties are objects (which are always passed by reference) you don't even need to create the references explicitly:

```
class Foo
{
    private Datetime $when;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->when = new DateTime('1950-12-31');
    }

    public function getWhen(): DateTime
    {
        return $this->when;
    }
}

$f = new Foo();
$w = $f->getWhen();
$w->modify('+50 years');
var_dump($w, $f);
```

```
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2000-12-31 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Madrid"
}
object(Foo)#1 (1) {
  ["when":"Foo":private]=>
  object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2000-12-31 00:00:00.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(13) "Europe/Madrid"
  }
}
```

This doesn't contradict the documentation you've quoted. The property itself is unreachable:

```
$f->when;
// PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property Foo::$when
```

References are a different language feature. Perhaps it's easier to understand with this other example:

```
function a(){
    $local_variable = 1;
    b($local_variable);
    echo "b modified a's local variable: $local_variable\n";
}

function b(&$number)
{
    echo "b can read a's local variable: $number\n";
    $number++;
}

a();
```

```
b can read a's local variable: 1
b modified a's local variable: 2
```

Comment: In the case of an object, yes this would be perfectly normal because of the instancing method PHP uses. This way you can change an object even without referencing it.

In my described case I don't use an object like you do in your first example.

In the second example you provided, you use functions to separate scopes. 

This doesn't completely relate to my question. Though after thinking about for a few days, the behavior I mentioned has to be intentional and exposes what you want to expose. In short it's an optional way to make a private variable public.

Comment: The key point is that references are a feature of their own and they don't have different behaviour in the context of class methods, thus my two examples.